# What is a non-algebraic expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, terminology, definition

To me the definition of " algebraic expression" is not absolutely clear.

Note : the context here is high school algebra, college algebra ( not abstract algebra).

Maybe counter-examples and a "counter-definition" ( if I may say this) could be usefull to grasp more easily the concept.

What are the sufficient/ necessary conditions for an expression not to qualify as algebraic?

Comment: What definition of 'algebraic expression' are you referring to?

Comment: @Berci. I'm referring to the standard definition in high school / college algebra textbooks. ( My question does not deal with abtsract algebra). I think this wikipedia definition reflects the standard definition : <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_expression>

Comment: Well, according to that definition, e.g. $|x|,\ \max(x,y),\ \sin(x)$ are not algebraic expressions..